# Looping through records and assigning to a hashtable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, hashtable

I have a SQL table laid out like the below

```
QuestionNumber  UserAnswer

1                   4
2                   11
3                   3
4                   2
5                   Y
6                   5
7                   4
8                   1
9                   34
10                  3
```

Im trying to loop through each value and assign it to a hashtable and then return the hashtable etc

```
 SqlConnection Connection = new SQLAccess().CreateConnection();
                SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("GetAllExamAnswersForUser", Connection);
                Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
                SqlDataReader da = Command.ExecuteReader();


    while (da.Read())
                    {
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber1", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber2", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber3", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber4", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber5", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber6", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber7", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber8", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber9", da["UserAnswer"]);
                        Details.Add("QuestionNumber10", da["UserAnswer"]);

    }
```

But no matter what i do da["UserAnswer"] is always the first answer...how can i loop through each row in my table and return the values?

Please can someone help me and put me out of my misery.... :-(

Comment: set a break point in your code, check da.HasRows, and the total count of rows.  How certain are you getting the sql data?  You didnt post how you got the data.

Comment: You should use a `Dictionary<T, V>` rather than a HashTable.

Comment: Iv checked an it does have rows, a total of 10...iv added the rest of my method

Answer (score 4):

> But no matter what i do da["UserAnswer"] is always the first answer...

Hmm, I would think it is always the *last* answer. You overwrite all previous ones.

You get a new record each time you go through the while loop, and  QuestionNumber is a column too:

```
   while (da.Read())
   {
         string answer = da["UserAnswer"];
         string question = da["QuestionNumber"];
         Details.Add(question, answer);           // one per record
    }
```

Or when you want to (re)number by yourself:

```
   int i = 1;
   while (da.Read())
   {
        //Details.Add("QuestionNumber1", da["UserAnswer"]);
        //Details.Add("QuestionNumber2", da["UserAnswer"]);
        //...

         Details.Add("QuestionNumber" + i, da["UserAnswer"]);
         i = i + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Results are technically unordered.  You should get the question number from the row, not from an index.

Comment: Then it's really time to use the Debugger... This code ought to work, either you are getting an Exception (conversion error?) and/or the SP returns faulty data. Could any answer be NULL ?

Comment: Sorry my fault i miss placed something the example you have given me is working the way i want thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

.Read advances one record at a time. Each of your da["UserAnswer"] calls is operating on the same record.